# How do I remove the whitespace in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to submit this into myprogramminglab, everything else is correct but it wants me to remove this whitespace that doesn't seem to exist.

```
num_males = int(input('Enter number of males:'))
num_females = int(input('Enter number of females:'))
total_students = num_males + num_females

percent_male = num_males * 100 / total_students
percent_female = num_females * 100 / total_students

print('Percent males: {:.0f}%' .format(percent_male)**X**,
       '\nPercent females: {:.0f}%' .format(percent_female))
```

I labeled where the spacing is with an ***X***

Am I just not seeing something?

[image: here are the results I keep getting]

Comment: no idea what myprogramminglab is but does it mean the newline before Percent females?

Comment: I tried taking that out, but then they end up on the same line and the spacing is still there. I uploaded a picture if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass multiple arguments to [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), spaces are inserted between each value by default. If you want to suppress the space separators, set the `sep` keyword argument to an empty string:

```
print(
    'Percent males: {:.0f}%' .format(percent_male),
    '\nPercent females: {:.0f}%' .format(percent_female),
    sep='',
)
```

Alternatively, you could pass a single string to `print` to avoid the separator behavior entirely:

```
print("Percent males: {:.0f}%\nPercent females: {:.0f}%".format(
    percent_male,
    percent_female,
))
```

Comment: Something so simple, now I just feel like a jackass. Thank you!